# get all user.name from a database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm guessing how to retrieve just the names of all the records from a database. The easy way is something like this:

```
@user=User.all
@list=[]
@user.each do|u|
  @list.push(u.name)
end
```

but I'm sure if it has to be a oneline query on irb that must fit. Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should try :

User.all.collect(&:name)

or

User.select("name")

Comment: User class is still being instantiated for each result. Depending on your memory constraints this may not be a problem, but nevertheless it’s using up memory that just didn’t need to be used. Try `pluck`

Answer (score 13):

There is a built-in method to select one attribute, [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

```
User.pluck :name
```

Comment: this works in the console but causes errors in my app